# SQL query regarding MIN() and returning another value from row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called BCS, and two columns that I need to use named HPTS and Team. I need to list the team name of the team which the lowest value in HPTS.

(I am doing this in Access if this matters)

Currently what I have is the following:

```
SELECT TEAM, MIN(HPTS)
FROM BCS
GROUP BY Team
```

This is giving me the minimum value for each team in the HTPS column, but this is useless information to me since there is only one value per team in that column anyway.

I am able to just get the minimum value without the corresponding team by using:

```
SELECT MIN(HPTS)
FROM BCS
```

but I need to have the team name as well. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I think it may have something to do with using the JOIN function but I am not sure.

Comment: What should it do in the case of ties?

Answer (score 2):

In TSQL, and I believe in Access/Jet, too, you can use the TOP N clause as long as you also use an ORDER BY to determine what's actually on the "top".  It's probably more efficient than the subqueries mentioned by others:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Team, HPTS FROM BCS ORDER BY HPTS ASCENDING
```

The ASCENDING is the default so you can leave it out, but it's so important when using TOP that I usually put it in.  And welcome to the wonderful world o' SQL!

Comment: Note that in JET this might return more than one record.

Comment: If a single result is required and you do not care that there is a matching result, you can `ORDER BY HPTS, AnyUniqueFieldInTheTable`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use subquery here.

```
SELECT * FROM BCS WHERE HPTS IN (SELECT MIN(HPTS) FROM BCS)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just ordering it by HPTS from lowest and limiting it to 1 row?

```
SELECT TEAM, HPTS FROM BCS order by HPTS LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That's MySQL syntax.  AFAIK Access uses `SELECT TOP N` syntax like SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this out but please try the following

```
SELECT TEAM FROM BCS where HPTS = (SELECT MIN(HPTS) FROM BCS)
```